# How to get custom payloads inside the "webhookPayloads" section for the detectIntent API response for Dialogflow CX?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-cx

I currently call the detectIntent API with the query text and read the custom payload from webhook response.
The response comes under the "fulfillmentPayload" along with the agent responses defined in the console.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4500;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/v3beta1/webhook', (req, res) => {
try {
    const customData = {
    customField: 'This is a custom value',
    anotherField: 'Another value',
    };

    const response = {
    fulfillmentResponse: {
        messages: [
        {
            text: {
            text: ['This is a response from the webhook.'],
            },
        },
        ],
        payload: [
        {
            payload: customData,
        },
        ],
        languageCode: "en",
    },
    };

    res.json(response);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error handling webhook request:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
}
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Here's the response I get when I trigger the agent with a POST call:

```
{
"responseId": "f19bebde-d035-46b6-9da8-165g656acs18",
"queryResult": {
    "text": "Hi",
    "languageCode": "en",
    "responseMessages": [
        {
            "text": {
                "text": [
                    "Hi there! How can I help you?"
                ]
            },
            "responseType": "HANDLER_PROMPT"
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "text": [
                    "This is a response from the webhook."
                ]
            },
            "responseType": "HANDLER_PROMPT"
        }
    ],
    "webhookPayloads": [
        {}
    ],
....
....
....
```

How do I get customData under "webhookPayloads"?

I have been using [Dialogflow CX documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3beta1).
I have not been able to get any payload under webhookPayloads so far.